# A friend function of a class that can only be used by a specific class

Tags: c++, function, class, friend, access-control

I have three different classes `A`, `B`, and `C`. Can I create a function, `f`, that can access the private members of `A` and have `f` callable only by `B` (and not by `C`)?

I am looking for an alternative to making class `B` a friend of class `A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Make the friend function in question take as an argument class with `private` constructor of which `B` is the only `friend`. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A;
class B;

template <typename T>
class Arg {
    friend T; // only T can make Arg<T>
};

void foo(A& a, Arg<B> );  // only B can make a Arg<B>
                          // so foo is only callable by B

class B {
public:
    void bar(A& a) {       // public for demonstration purposes
        foo(a, Arg<B>{});  // but this can just as easily be private
    }
};

class A {
    friend void foo(A&, Arg<B>);   // foo can access A's internals
    int x;
public:
    void print() { std::cout << x << '\n'; }
};

void foo(A& a, Arg<B> ) { a.x = 42; }

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    b.bar(a);
    a.print();
}
```

`foo` is a `friend` of `A` that can only be used by `B`.

Answer (score 0):

If you fully-qualify the friend function, then yes, you can restrict.  Something like this should allow B but not C.

```
class A
{
   private:
      int a;
      int b;

  friend int B::accessInternalsViaFriend();
}

class B
{
   .
   .
   .
   public:
      int accessInternalsViaFriend();
};
```

Comment: A `friend` can only be a class type or a non-member function. You cannot restrict a `friend` to a specific class member. So either `B` as a whole is a `friend`, or not at all.